# I Don't Quite Understand of What This Footnote Means

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

[image: Image of the Footnote]

Hello, I'm an undergrad CS student that somehow got a physics class in my lecture.

So, I got homework from my lecturer about this [5] footnote. My lecturer wants me to find an interval of $F$ in this problem for which no motion occurs and $μ_km_1 \gt m_2$ (as mentioned in the [5] footnote).

But, I don't quite understand what does it trying to say. I've tried to put $a = 0$ and still confused with how to link that equation to get an Interval of $F$, especially in $μ_km_1 \gt m_2$ thing, what does it mean? I'm confused.

So, any answer is appreciated folks, Thanks in Advance, and sorry for my bad English

Note: This was taken from Physics for Scientists and Engineers (6th Edition) by John Jewett and Raymond Serway, Chapter 5 The Laws of Motion, Page 136.

Comment: The question is almost homework help.. you need to make it so that it is helpful for general audience

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve this as a statics problem twice: once with the maximum friction acting with F and again with the maximum friction against F.  In each case you are looking for F.